# Java not displaying the last output

Tags: java, output, enter

I was solving a problem on codeforces and there was a runtime error, apparently the last output is not displayed unless I press the enter key.

Here is the code:

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int tests;
        tests = sc.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
            long n, m, number, result;
            n = sc.nextLong();
            m = sc.nextLong();
            number = sc.nextLong();
            if (number % n == 0) {
                result = (n - 1) * m + (number / n);
            } else {
                result = (((number % n) - 1) * m) + (number / n) + 1;
            }
            System.out.println(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Its a very simple problem and I think my answer is correct but I have problem in displaying the output
Here is a link to the problem:
https://codeforces.com/contest/1506/problem/A

When I try the following input:

```
5
1 1 1
2 2 3
3 5 11
100 100 7312
1000000 1000000 1000000000000
```

I get the correct output, but like this:

```
1
2
9
1174
```

The last output only shows when I press enter, it then displays 1000000000000.
I believe that the runtime error I am receiving from codeforces is because the bot that is correcting the problem is waiting endlessly for an enter key.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?
I usually use C language with codeforces and this is the first time I used java so sorry for any obvious mistakes.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not sure about your problem. Your program works correctly. Please describe _excactly_ what you are doing.

Comment: Additionally ... you always must press the Enter button after inputting something on the CLI. Otherwise the scanner does not know about _next tokens_.

Comment: Works fine for me too.  Looking at the code, I expected that to be true.  I assume that the problem is specific to codeforces.  If that's true, I don't know how we can help you.  I, at least, am not at all familiar with that environment.  The code is right.  The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry I edited the problem, you need to enter the input in the the way displayed in the problem, not all on one line.

Comment: Well, if there is a _newline_ character at the end of each line, then the scanner will have some tokens. You then have to press the Enter button after the last line. Alternatively, you could also copy another newline character and paste that also.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the problem is that you are pasting in data that contains newline characters, but that does not contain a newline character at the end of it.  I was able to reproduce the problem, or something similar, by doing that.  When I added a newline to the end of what I was pasting, the code worked the way you would want it to.

Without a newline at the end of the paste, the last number isn't immediately seen by the scanner.  The reason for this is that the last character is a digit, so the scanner can't know if you're going to type more digits.  You have to enter a non-digit character for it to move on and complete the operation.  It doesn't have to be a newline, just some whitespace character (like a space).

Comment: I just tried what you said, but sorry it didn't work, maybe I misunderstood you, can you please show me what you edited in the code?

Comment: Hi @KamelYehya - Did you ever figure this out?  I guess I  missed seeing your comment way back when.  I wasn't talking about any change to the code, but rather with how you're entering the data.  Let me know if I can still clarify.

Answer (score 0):

you can enter the input as described in codeforces, but you have to save your output some where and print the result at the end:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int tests;
tests = sc.nextInt();
List<Long> outputList=new ArrayList<Long>();
for (int i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
    long n, m, number, result;
    n = sc.nextLong();
    m = sc.nextLong();
    number = sc.nextLong();
    if (number % n == 0)
        result = (n - 1) * m + (number / n);
    else
        result = (((number % n) - 1) * m) + (number / n) + 1;
    outputList.add(result);
}
for(Long x : outputList)
    System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it's still a runtime error because the compiler is waiting for an enter key for some reason

Comment: yes you have to press enter key at the end (when you paste your input). how do u want to input your data? 5+enter+1+1+1+enter or paste the whole input and then press enter key?

Comment: according to codeforces the output has to be displayed once the input is entered, no enter key.

Answer (score 0):

While the solution could be more Java-ish and also simpler as

```
long n = sc.nextLong();
long m = sc.nextLong();
long number = sc.nextLong() - 1;
System.out.println(1 + number / n + (number % n) * m);
```

(and in fact C allows declaring variables on the fly too since C99, so for 20+ years)
the issue you are facing seems to be related to Codeforces.

When working with standard input, you can edit what you type, just try moving around with the arrows and deleting/adding characters. The actual input will happen when you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, that's why you have to press it. Up to that point you are in the line-editor of the operating system (just like in a command prompt) or what the IDE places in front of you, and the Java code absolutely can't do anything about it. Even if you want to read a single byte from `System.in`, you would not get it until the user presses <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you can test it with a single line of code, `System.out.println(System.in.read());`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with the package name.
In coding programs like codeforces you shouldn't add the package name otherwise it will result in a runtime error.
Regarding the enter key, that wasn't the problem.
As some of you pointed out you should always press the enter key, otherwise the scanner won't know about the next token.